# Is IS_ROLEMEMBER available in SQL Server 2012 or 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, compatibility

Are these functions available in SQL Server 2012 or older?

```
select IS_ROLEMEMBER ('db_owner');
select IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin');
```

I can not find any compatibility information in the online documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/is-rolemember-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: It looks like these functions are available from SQL Server **2016** onwards - but not for older versions

Comment: it is available in `SQL Server 2008R2`. I don't have any order version to test

Comment: able to run successfully on `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2`

Comment: yes, this is available in sql server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Is_RoleMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ee677633%28v%3dsql.110%29) was introduced in SQL Server 2012.

[Is_SrvRoleMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms176015%28v%3dsql.90%29) was introduced in SQL Server 2005 itself.

You can see when a particular feature was introduced by going through below links. These changes are coming under **Database Engine Enhancements => Database Engine Security Enhancements**

- [What is New in SQL 2005](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170363(v=sql.90).aspx)
- [What is New in SQL 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500435(v=sql.110).aspx)

To see all the historical information about SQL Server versions, below link is very helpful: https://www.sqlshack.com/history-sql-server-evolution-sql-server-features/